# How to avoid IU freezing when typing more than 6 keys at once on wired Keychron k2v2?

Tags: 20.04, keyboard

I have a Dell's Vostro with Ubuntu 20.04. Using a wired [Keychron's K2V2](https://www.keychron.com/products/keychron-k2-wireless-mechanical-keyboard), when I type more than 6 keys at once, the entire UI freezes for a few seconds and after that, all keys are registered/printed where they should. Using the same keyboard with Win10 on other laptop works fine, as well the native laptop's keyboard on my Vostro with Ubuntu.

I would like to know how to avoid this behavior since it's not hardware specfic (same keyboard worked on Win10 and native keyboard worked as well on Ubuntu)

Comment: ask ubuntu is a Q&A resource. what is your question?

Comment: sorry, I'll edit my question